# Display only posts from a specific parent category

Tags: posts, categories

I have a category structure similar to the below:

- Grand parent cat

  - Parent cat 1

    - Child cat
    - Child cat
    - Child cat
    - Child cat
  - Parent cat 2

    - Child cat
    - Child cat
    - Child cat

If I query `Parent cat 2` for posts, I get all posts in that category AND its child categories.

How do I query the Parent cat and exclude posts in its children?

Answer (score 5):

```
$the_category_id    = 10;
$new_posts          = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type'     => 'post',
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'tax_query'     => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy'          => 'category',
            'terms'             => array( $the_category_id ),
            'field'             => 'term_id',
            'operator'          => 'AND',
            'include_children'  => false
        )
    )
) );
```

So basically the difference is `include_children` parameter.

Comment: However, for the builtin taxonomy `category`, `include_children` parameter is set to false when you query using 'category__and', 'category__in' & 'cat' parameter. But for custom taxonomy, you will need to use that.